# Why is my switch not working?

Tags: javascript, html, switch-statement

I have a switch statement to give you a letter mark if you enter a number mark. I am not getting any errors from chrome so i don't know what i am doing wrong. Would i be just formatting it wrong?

```
<html>
   <body>
<h1>Rank Your Mark!!</h1>
Enter your mark to rank it.

 <input type="number" name="grade" id="mark">
 <input type="button" name="mark" id="grade" value="Rate" onclick="rateMark()">

      <script>
function rateMark(){
  switch(grade)
  {
    case"F":
      mark > 50;
      break;

    case"D":
      mark >= 50 && mark <=59.9;
      break;

    case"C":
      mark >= 60 && mark <=69.9;
      break;

    case"B":
      mark >= 70 && mark <= 79.9;
      break;

    case"A":
      mark >= 80 && mark <= 89.9;
      break;

    case"A+":
      mark >= 90 && mark <= 100;
      break;
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You got a" + mark;
}
  </script>
  <br>
<p id="demo"></p>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: `switch` doesn’t work like that; you need a chain of `if`/`else if`.

Comment: @Blakethepatton do you knoiw what i am doing wrong since it shows a [object HTMLInputElement] and not the letter ?

Comment: @Blakethepatton: Well, I originally assumed that `grade` was a number and the letter grade was supposed to be the output, but I suppose it’s possible that they want “You got a >= 60 && <= 69.9”? Hard to tell.

Comment: its supposed to be if its over 60 and under or equal to 69.9 then its that case. @Ryan

Comment: Just FYI, you're missing a space after "You got a" inside your quotation marks

Comment: @Ryan I think you're original assumption was right. Input a number and get a letter, but with OP's code having an input field with ID `grade` and name `mark`, and another input field with ID `mark` and name `grade` it's pretty difficult to figure out.

Comment: No, @ryan is correct, your switch isn't going to do anything. You're switching based on a variable not set and then you aren't returning anything from the cases. And also you're missing a default case.

Comment: where is grade defined?

Answer (score 2):

You're not using the right way, check how it works [here.](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp)

What you're doing is compare if **grade** variable is "F", "D", "C".....

Use `if` and `else if` and put your statements into them, like this:

```
var mark = document.getElementById('mark').value // gets the input value to "mark" variable
if(mark >= 70 && mark <= 79.9){
   // do something here
} else if(mark >= 80 && mark <= 89.9){
   // do another thing here
}
```

so on...

Comment: Except this still isn't correct.  You need to be using `mark.value` if you want to actually get the value of the input.

Comment: Yes, but he didn't even get the input's value. I just wanted to show him how to use statements presuming that its value would be on the mark variable

Comment: @KyleMartin using `mark.value` will not fix the problem since the OP is missing a statement like `var mark = document.getElementById("mark");`. `var mark = document.getElementById("mark").value;` is cleaner anyway

Comment: Well, that's what I thought too, although this JSFiddle says otherwise.  https://jsfiddle.net/8ze5xopj/2/  I'm not quite sure why this works though, to be honest.

Comment: @KyleMartin I stand corrected. I've never seen someone refer to the element that way before, but as you say it does work without the `getElementById` and it does require `mark.value` when done like that

Comment: @KScandrett is right. I presumed `var mark = document.getElementById("mark").value`would be added before it, so I focused on the statement to answer. I'll improve my answer anyway

Answer (score 0):

See this:

```html
<body>
<h1>Rank Your Mark!!</h1>
Enter your mark to rank it.

 <input type="number" name="grade" id="mark">
 <input type="button" name="mark" id="grade" value="Rate" onclick="rateMark()">

      <script>
      function rateMark(){
    mark = document.getElementById("mark").value
        if (mark < 50) {
          mark = "F"
        } else if (mark >= 50 && mark <=59.9) {
          mark = "E"
        } else if (mark >= 60 && mark <=69.9) {
         mark = "D"
   } else if (mark >= 70 && mark <= 79.9) {
          mark = "C"
        } else if (mark >= 80 && mark <= 89.9) {
           mark = "B"
        }  else if (mark >= 90 && mark <= 100) {
         mark = "A"
        }
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You got a " + mark;
      }
  </script>
  <br>
<p id="demo"></p>
   </body>
```